# how to access theme toolbar breakpoint properties?

Tags: material-ui, jss

I am using the material-ui themeProvider and trying to access all height values from the default theme in a style:

```
makeStyles(theme => createStyles({
 ...
 marginTop: -theme.mixins.toolbar.minHeight, // works
 [`${theme.breakpoints.up('xs')} and (orientation: landscape)`]: {
   marginTop: -theme.mixins.toolbar.@media___????.minHeight },
  [theme.breakpoints.up('sm')]: { 
    marginTop: -theme.mixins.toolbar.@media___????.minHeight },
```

[image]

How do I access the @media values?

Answer (score 0):

Same as you will access object properties using bracket notation

`theme.mixins.toolbar['@media (min-width:0px) and (orientation: landscape)'].minHeight`